# How to download SAML XML metadata from Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, saml

I have an enterprise application that implements SAML SSO, and I have a new client who wishes to use it. This feature works with other clients. However, the application requires that the client download the SAML XML metadata from the Azure server and hand it off to me to be integrated with the application. The user interface for Azure has changed within the past couple of years, and the link that previously provided the SAML XML metadata is broken.

```
(Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise Applications -> My Application from the List -> Single Sign On -> View step-by-step instructions -> SAML XML Metadata)
```

I have tried clicking on the link in Chrome, FireFox, IE, and Edge. It worked for none of them, and Edge crashed my computer when I tried clicking on the link. This link always gave me trouble in FireFox, but it used to work in other browsers two years ago.

The federation metadata XML file from Azure does **not** work with my application. It **must** use the SAML XML metadata.

Can anyone tell me how I can obtain the SAML XML metadata in Azure?

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: still seems to be broken 3 months later. I downloaded the Federation Metadata XML and it seems to contain what I needed.